# function .autocomplete creates unwanted div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the .autocomplete function from jQuery UI, but something is working not quite well.
Upon searching and hovering on a result it generates some unwanted DIVs *(containing tips such as "X matches found" or the value of the element I hover on)* that I have no idea how to handle.
This is the code I'm using.

```
$( "#element" ).autocomplete({
    source: array
});
```

After some research I found that I can edit the value of those messages by adding:

```
$( "#element" ).autocomplete({
  source: array,
    messages: {  
        noResults: null,
        results: null
      }
    }
});
```

By doing this, the DIVs are still generated (although they're empty). But sadly this is as far as I my knowledge goes. How can I disable the generation of these elements?

Comment: Hey @IanWing can you please generate https://jsfiddle.net/ for that

Comment: `messages` is not an option for jQuery UI Autocomplete: https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I have not included the jQuery UI stylesheet to the file. Once I placed it in place, it started working properly.

Comment: It still creats DIV elements, but at least they're not showing on page.